How to config timeout for all instances of IRequestClient in masstransit?
I have an application with masstransit and rabbitmq. some of my requests resulted in timeout.
I tried using UseTimeout but it did not work:
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(configuration["RabbitMqUri"], h =>
        {
            h.Username(configuration["RabbitMqUsername"]);
            h.Password(configuration["RabbitMqPassword"]);
        });
        cfg.UseTimeout(timeoutConfigurator => timeoutConfigurator.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
}
}

I know i can set timeout as following:
private async Task<Result> TempTimeout(IRequestClient<TempTimeoutCommand> requestClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var res = await requestClient.GetResponse<TempTimeoutResponse>(
            new TempTimeoutCommand(),
            cancellationToken,
            RequestTimeout.After(s: 100)
        );

        return res.Message.Result;
    }

Is it possible to configure timeout for the whole application?

UseTimeout is not the way. Currently there isn't a method to configure the client factory with a specific timeout, but I have a commit pending that will add the ability to configure the default request timeout.
It will look like:
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetDefaultRequestTimeout(...)


thanks very much, this is exactly what i need, any estimate on when to expect it?

It will be released with 8.2.2, which is currently in prerelease form.
